# Hive XOR function for string?

Tags: string, hive, hiveql, xor

I want to select a data either A column equals 'X' or B column equals 'X' 
but not both of them equal 'X'. Is there such a function in HQL?

Answer (score 2):

Try below query instead of tablename use your tablename

```
    SELECT * FROM ( 
       SELECT
        CASE WHEN COLUMNA='X' AND COLUMNB<>'X' THEN COLUMNA 
        CASE WHEN COLUMNA<>'X' AND COLUMNB='X' THEN COLUMNB 
        END AS XORCOMBO
        FROM TABLENAME
                 )X
WHERE XORCOMBO IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This seems a turn around method by adding an extract column and using it as the filter. Thanks @saravanatn

Comment: NP.  Welcome Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does have bitwise XOR arithmetic operator. It can be used on any numeric data type for ex. `A ^ B`.

More details can be found in hive official documentation:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ArithmeticOperators

Comment: @ Jainik. That is true. Thanks